My custom login page redirects in loop after update to Spring Security 6
I am trying to update an application from Spring Boot 2.7.18 to Spring Boot 3.0.0. However, I am facing an issue due to (I believe) the update from Spring Security 5.7.11 to 6.0.0. The issue is that I setted a custom login page, but when I try to access some endpoint, I am redirected in loop to this login page until the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is thrown from the browser.
I tried to simplify my application to keep only what is related to the issue. In Spring 2.7, I have a SecurityConfig:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.formLogin(login -> login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/userAuth")
                .permitAll()
        );
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}

and a MvcConfig:
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public static final String FORWARD = "forward:/";

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}")
                .setViewName(FORWARD);
        registry.addViewController("/**/{spring:\\w+}")
                .setViewName(FORWARD);
        registry.addViewController("/{spring:\\w+}/**{spring:?!(\\.js|\\.css)$}")
                .setViewName(FORWARD);
    }
}

My Resources files is organized as following:
src
| main
| | java
| | | resources
| | | | static
| | | | | asset-manifest.json
| | | | | favicon.ico
| | | | | index.html
| | | | | logo192.png
| | | | | logo512.png
| | | | | manifest.json
| | | | | robots.txt
| | | | | static
| | | | | | css ...
| | | | | | js ...
| | | | | | media ...

Where in index.html I can reach the /login and / (main page) of my frontend.
My pom has the following dependencies (I am using Java 17):
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


And my application.properties:
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher

In Spring 2.7, this works just fine, and I am redirected to http://localhost:8080/login when accessing http://localhost:8080/.
I updated to Spring Boot 3.0.0 with the following change:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
                .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/static/**")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.formLogin(login -> login
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/userAuth")
                .permitAll()
        );
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}

And that causes the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
When using Spring 3.0, that is the initialization log:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)

2024-05-08T15:38:38.352-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] c.e.s.SecuritySpring3Application         : Starting SecuritySpring3Application using Java 21.0.2 with PID 2928 
2024-05-08T15:38:38.355-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] c.e.s.SecuritySpring3Application         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-08T15:38:39.407-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-05-08T15:38:39.418-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-08T15:38:39.419-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2024-05-08T15:38:39.513-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-08T15:38:39.514-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1104 ms
2024-05-08T15:38:39.624-03:00 TRACE 2928 --- [           main] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration@28f4f300}
2024-05-08T15:38:39.628-03:00  WARN 2928 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 8aa72fad-3d16-4a4e-9385-7a88ff0d4549

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2024-05-08T15:38:39.736-03:00 DEBUG 2928 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for ExactUrl [processUrl='/login?error']
2024-05-08T15:38:39.758-03:00 DEBUG 2928 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for ExactUrl [processUrl='/userAuth']
2024-05-08T15:38:39.758-03:00 DEBUG 2928 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for ExactUrl [processUrl='/login']
2024-05-08T15:38:39.758-03:00 DEBUG 2928 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/static/**']
2024-05-08T15:38:39.758-03:00 DEBUG 2928 --- [           main] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request
2024-05-08T15:38:39.766-03:00 TRACE 2928 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2024-05-08T15:38:39.768-03:00 TRACE 2928 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2024-05-08T15:38:39.769-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@70721c12, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@769bd849, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1c3259fa, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7209ffb5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1d8b0500, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@294f9d50, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6807a356, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7ddd84b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@101ca8da, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3eb292cd, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@40ac6b76]
2024-05-08T15:38:39.894-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2024-05-08T15:38:40.056-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-05-08T15:38:40.063-03:00  INFO 2928 --- [           main] c.e.s.SecuritySpring3Application         : Started SecuritySpring3Application in 2.136 seconds (process running for 3.033)

When i access http://localhost:8080/, I get the following log in loop until ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is thrown in the browser:
2024-05-08T15:55:41.472-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/?continue to session
2024-05-08T15:55:41.472-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-05-08T15:55:41.472-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@6232ffdb, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@330c1f61, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@59ce792e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7c2dfa2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6c6017b9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4d68b571, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@404db674, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@50f097b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@37d28f02, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@313f8301, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5a0bef24]] (1/1)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (6/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/userAuth', POST]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.475-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (11/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to ExactUrl [processUrl='/login?error'] - [permitAll] (1/5)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to ExactUrl [processUrl='/userAuth'] - [permitAll] (2/5)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession A87EC0FB88AF6B79CCB47A062D5602B1 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A87EC0FB88AF6B79CCB47A062D5602B1], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A87EC0FB88AF6B79CCB47A062D5602B1], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /login] with attributes [permitAll]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /login] with attributes [permitAll]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
2024-05-08T15:55:41.476-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@6232ffdb, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@330c1f61, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@59ce792e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7c2dfa2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6c6017b9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4d68b571, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@404db674, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@50f097b5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@37d28f02, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@313f8301, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@5a0bef24]] (1/1)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (6/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/userAuth', POST]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (11/11)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to ExactUrl [processUrl='/login?error'] - [permitAll] (1/5)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to ExactUrl [processUrl='/userAuth'] - [permitAll] (2/5)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to ExactUrl [processUrl='/login'] - [permitAll] (3/5)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/static/**'] - [permitAll] (4/5)
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A87EC0FB88AF6B79CCB47A062D5602B1], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.477-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A87EC0FB88AF6B79CCB47A062D5602B1], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
2024-05-08T15:55:41.478-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.478-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
2024-05-08T15:55:41.478-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /] with attributes [authenticated] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2be95d31], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.478-03:00 TRACE 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A87EC0FB88AF6B79CCB47A062D5602B1], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:77) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:253) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    [...]
2024-05-08T15:55:41.479-03:00 DEBUG 16468 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/?continue to session

What am I doing wrong? Do I need other configurations to keep the behavior of Spring Boot 2.7?
I updated here my full and working project in Spring 2.7: https://github.com/caiovsch/security-spring-2. And with the changes in Spring 3.0: https://github.com/caiovsch/security-spring-3.

why havnt you included your logs?

you are claiming you get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS but your logs are clearly stating: AccessDeniedException: Access is denied please update and put some effort into providing us correct information if you are serious about wanting help.

also in the first log you see there is a default password posted in the logs, this means that your security configuration is not picked up, this is stated in the getting started section in the chapter in the docs named pretty convinently getting started (which i suggest you read), try adding @EnableWebSecurity to the security config class. If that doesnt work make sure your config is in a folder beneath your main class in the folder tree. All this is basic getting started knowledge stated in the docs.

It's ocorrus because the spring chanched the way of manipule the frontend files (static files).
now, for work the acess of the frontend files, you need add the annotation .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll() in your authorizeHttpRequests.
Please chanche your SecurityFilterChain to:
@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/static/**")).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );
    http.formLogin(login -> login
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/userAuth")
            .permitAll()
    );
    http.csrf().disable();
    return http.build();
}

}
Font: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12463

Adding
requests.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
to http.authorizeRequests worked for me

.anyRequest().authenticated() should be last if available many ones, otherwise java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure mvcMatchers after anyRequest.
